# How to find a subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we let: $U= \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a,b,c,d,e\}, A= \{2,4,b,c\}$ and $B= \{2,3,6,7,b,d,e\}$.

How do you find all subsets of $A$ with cardinality of $2$?

Comment: Do you understand the question? I don't. Do you mean 'the subsetS'?

Comment: Yes, subsets @GitGud

Comment: Cardinality is the number of elements of the set.

Comment: You seem to be changing your questions a lot. If you have another question, please, do not edit the question which already has been answered. You should post a new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

{x,y} where x and y are distinct elements of A is a subset of A with cardinality two.
There are 4C2 = 6 such combinations.

Comment: {2,4}, {2,b}, {2,c}, {4,b}, {4,c}, {b,c}